# how to concatinate 2 uint32 to uint64 in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have pairs of numpy uint32s, which are each half of a uint64.  How do I concatenate them easily?

ie i have something like

```
w = np.uint32(775329792) 
x = np.uint32(46919588)

wx = np.uint64(?)
```

Comment: How do you want the concatenation to happen? Big-endian? Little-endian? Native-endian?

Comment: Hi, i think it is little endian - in this case - but i guess it is more important to know in the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [bitshift](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) operator

```
wx = (w << 32) + x;
```

The above uses w as the most significant 32-bits and then adds in x as the least significant 32-bits.

Comment: Seems to work well.  I've added explict data types in my version - not sure if it makes too much difference - but i guess it might make it easier for someone to know what I'm trying t do...